# Android: The borders of TableRow of TableLayout are shaken once data is inserted programmatically

Tags: android, border, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I am trying to achieve something like below the below image:

[image]

And uptil now I have been able to somewhat achieve this, but after the data is inserted the entire layout is shaken as the borders are not upto the mark as per the requirement. The acheived image is as below:
[image]

Can someone please help me on how can I achieve it perfectly?
The xml layout is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorGreySolitude"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/v15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/v25dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
    android:text="Reconcile Summary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBokaraGrey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/v10dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/v15dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorRedNew"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorRedNew"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/v20dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/v10dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/v12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/v10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/v5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize14" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_total_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize14" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                    android:text="dfvsdf"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Cash"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Card"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Custom"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="Actual"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="19,800"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="49,800"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="10,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>                </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="System"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="20,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize18" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="50,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize18" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:text="10,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize18" />

                </LinearLayout>      </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_demi"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Difference"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize16" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_book"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="200"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize17" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_book"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="200"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize17" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/v10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_book"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize17" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:stretchColumns="*"/>
```

Any suggestions on what I can use other than TableLayout is welcomed. As applying borders to every cell is a very tedious job with Table Layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes applying borders to TableLayout is tedious.

There are a few tricks to make it slightly less tedious

1. You can add a divider view between TableRows to get your horizontal dividers (this does not work for all possible border combinations, but seems to work for what you want)
2. You can use a background drawable to create your cell borders and you only really need to set one side, I usually choose the right side therefore the last cell does not need a background.

So using a combination of above just for the Table part I was able to create:-

[image: Table]

Note what you wanted to achieve image is a bit blurry so could not tell the exact colour of the divider over the "Difference" row but it is easy to change.

Also to compact it more using `weightSum` and `layout_weight` is redundant as `TableRow` does it's own space calculations and ignores these values (You can set them because it is derived from a `LinearLayout` but the `stretchColumns` etc replaces the division of excess space)

Trimmed down table xml

```xml
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_red"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="Cash" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="Card" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Custom" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorRedNew"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_red"
                android:text="Actual" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="19,800" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="49,800" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="10,000" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_red"
                android:text="System" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="20,000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="50,000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="10,000" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorRedNew"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_red"
                android:text="Difference" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="20,000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                android:background="@drawable/right_border_grey"
                android:text="50,000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRedNew"
                android:text="0" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Drawables used:-

right_border_grey

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorTableLayoutDivider" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

right_border_red

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorRedNew" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! Really saved my hours of looking for solution on table borders!